# GCM pub/sub ios without content_available

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm subscribing to a gcm topic with my iOS device. In googles documentation (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) they say that the http-post should look like this:

> https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
>
> Content-Type:application/json
>
> Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
>
> {   "to": "/topics/foo-bar",   "data": {
>       "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",    } }

Using this doesn't get my iOS device notified. I have to include the content_available header and it's value HAS to be true. Otherwise, iOS device will not get notified.

Also, in the documentation, they say that I should look for the "from" in the notification that is sent to the iOS device, but that field is never there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your GcmService connected? Setting content_available to true means that the message is being sent through APNs. So I'd double check whether or not non APNs messages are being received, starting with making sure GcmService is connected.

Comment: What do you mean by connected GcmService? I'm executing this line of code at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(GCMConfig.defaultConfig()).

Comment: In the applicationDidBecomeActive callback you should call GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler in order to receive non APNs messages. Eg: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L88

Comment: Thanks! That changed everything.